# Type 'AbstractControl<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'FormControl<any>'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a **Parent component** displaying this custom component

```
                        \<app-select-template
                          \[options\]="languagesArray"
                          formControlName="homeLanguage"
                          **\[formControl\]**="correspondencePreferencesForm.controls\['homeLanguage'\]"
                          label="Home Language"
                          headerText="Select Home Language"
                          (selectionChange)="handleSelectionChange($event)"
                          \>
                        \</app-select-template\>
```

It is highlighting a TYPE error : *Type 'AbstractControl<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'FormControl<any>': defaultValue, registerOnChange, registerOnDisabledChangengtsc*

**Child Custom Component**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select-template',
  template: `
    <div class="w-full">
      <p class="pb-4 text-gems-primary-blue" [textContent]="headerText"></p>
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label [textContent]="label"></mat-label>
        <mat-select [formControlName]="formControlName" (selectionChange)="submitFormCtrVal(formControl, $event)">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.Description | uppercase">
            {{option.Description | uppercase}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class SelectTemplateComponent {
  @Input() options!: any[];
  @Input() label!: string;
  @Input() headerText!: string;
  @Input() formControlName!: string;
  @Input() formControl: FormControl = new FormControl();
  @Output() selectionChange = new EventEmitter();

  submitFormCtrVal(formControl: FormControl, event: any) {
    const selectedValue = event.value;
    const selectionData = {
      formControl: formControl,
      value: selectedValue
    };
    this.selectionChange.emit(selectionData);
  }
  

  
}
```

Please help

I have tried changing the control type to abstract and defining it as new Formcontrol. Nothing is working.

Comment: if you want to write a custom form element, you need to implement at least ControlValueAccessor and Validator. Please check this example code and its article.  https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-form-controls/#demoofafullyfunctionalcustomformcontrol

Comment: @Andriy Not necessarily. For a scenario of Reactive Forms nested groups you don't need an actual custom implementation of the ControlValueAccessor, because all you want might be to compose the different levels of the same formGroup from the root level. So like in my answer, we can leverage the `ngDefaultControl` selector of the default one (`DefaultValueAccessor`).

Comment: thanks @MihaiParaschivescu for pointing out :). I like your solution.

Answer (score 1):

When doing nested forms (either for Template driven or Reactive driven forms), you need a way to "chain" or propagate the parent formGroup to the child component. Otherwise Angular won't know on what formGroup he `formControlName` directive is to be linked to.

With the disclaimer that you haven't pasted all your code and so I had to assume how the missing parts look, you can see below that inside of the child component I grabbed (via dependency injection) parent formGroup and redeclared it in the html template, so that the mat-select formControlName can work on it:

**Parent component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    SelectTemplateComponent,
  ],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="correspondencePreferencesForm">
      <app-select-template
        [options]="languagesArray"
        formControlName="homeLanguage"
        ngDefaultControl
        label="Home Language"
        headerText="Select Home Language"
        (selectionChange)="handleSelectionChange($event)"/>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  readonly languagesArray = [{ Description: 'en' }, { Description: 'fr' }];

  correspondencePreferencesForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    homeLanguage: ['en'],
  });

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  handleSelectionChange(event: any): void {
    const targetFormControl =
      this.correspondencePreferencesForm.controls[event.formControlName];
    console.log('handleSelectionChange()', event.value, targetFormControl);
  }
}
```

**Child component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-select-template',
  template: `
    <div [formGroup]="formGroup" class="w-full">
      <p class="pb-4 text-gems-primary-blue" [textContent]="headerText"></p>
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label [textContent]="label"></mat-label>
        <mat-select [formControlName]="formControlName" (selectionChange)="submitFormCtrVal($event)">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.Description | uppercase">
            {{option.Description | uppercase}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  `,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    UpperCasePipe,
    MatSelectModule,
  ],
  styles: [],
})
export class SelectTemplateComponent {
  @Input() options!: any[];
  @Input() label!: string;
  @Input() headerText!: string;
  @Input() formControlName!: string;

  @Output() selectionChange = new EventEmitter();

  formGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(@Optional() private parentFormGroup: FormGroupDirective) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formGroup = this.parentFormGroup.form;
  }

  submitFormCtrVal(event: any) {
    const selectedValue = event.value;
    const selectionData = {
      formControlName: this.formControlName,
      value: selectedValue,
    };
    this.selectionChange.emit(selectionData);
  }
}
```

---

Inside the child component, these are the important parts, as they make the link with the parent:

`constructor(@Optional() private parentFormGroup: FormGroupDirective)`

`this.formGroup = this.parentFormGroup.form;`

`<div [formGroup]="formGroup" class="w-full">`

---

**Note 1.** As you can see I also improved the part with the `[formControl]` property binding that wasn't needed to reflect back via @Output() the target formControl that changed. You can simply rely on the `formControlName` binding and figure out as part of the parent component handler which is the target formControl that changed:

```
  handleSelectionChange(event: any): void {
    const targetFormControl =
      this.correspondencePreferencesForm.controls[event.formControlName];
    console.log('handleSelectionChange()', event.value, targetFormControl);
  }
```

**Note 2.** Another thing to mention is that my example is made with the new standalone components api, since that's how the latest version of Stackblitz generates the playground projects. But it would work without any issues also with the old modules related approach.

---

Working Stackblitz sample project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cstaxs?file=src%2Fmain.ts